# How can I upload a file to the bin directory of an Azure app service?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service

I have a file that I want to upload to an Azure app service and if the file already exists just overwrite it automatically.

I have tried

```
Invoke-RestMethod https://mywebapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/data/test.txt `
  -Headers @{ 'Authorization' = "Basic $Token" } `
  -Method 'PUT' `
  -InFile localtest.txt
```

But this is not the bin directory and I don't want to rename the file.

How can I do this using PowerShell?

Comment: What is the purpose of uploading it in `bin` directory because bin contains only `dll` files. Storing it in root directory is easily accessible. @Katherine

Comment: I need to upload certain dlls to the slot before i do a swap to production . how can i do it ?

Comment: You can add the dll file using kudu console from the App service editor as shown [here](https://i.imgur.com/gGy40ee.png). Did you try out this way? @Katherine

Answer (score 0):

To upload `dll` before swapping slots between production and other, I created a sample `staging` deployment slot by cloning settings from the main `production` slot app service.

[image]

After it is done, Go to Staging app service -> `Development Tools -> Advanced Tools -> Go to kudu console`.

Now click on `Tools -> Zip Push Deploy` and you will be able to view the `bin` directory as follows.

Upload the `dll` files by clicking on `+` beside `bin` as shown.

[image]